# Storing nodes at each level of depth in json object in seperate array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

i have a json, something like this

```
{
   "a": {
      "b1": "blah blah",
      "b2": "ahsbefbasef",
      "b3": "adsfad af"
   },
   "c": {
      "d1":"asef",
      "d2":"fefef",
      "d3":"ffgfgf"
   }
}
```

now i want to traverse through this json and get all the nodes-depth wise, as in i want to store nodes with 0 depth(a, c) in one array, nodes with depth 1 (c1,c2,c3,d1,d2,d3) in another array, and so on and so forth, basically breaking json object and storing nodes present at each depth in seperate array

Comment: do you know the maximum depth level, or it is not known?

Comment: @niklaz, it could be anything (generic json)

Comment: maybe you should try with recursive-iterator library https://github.com/nervgh/recursive-iterator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code to achieve your requirements. 
and in ECMAScript2015 (a.k.a. ES6), you can use the [spread operator](https://davidwalsh.name/spread-operator) to append multiple items at once:

I have benchmarked my code [here](http://jsben.ch/0nz6Z) , you can check below code is faster than accepted answer.

```js
var obj = {
  "a": {
    "b1": "blah blah",
    "b2": "ahsbefbasef",
    "b3": "adsfad af"
  },
  "c": {
    "d1": "asef",
    "d2": "fefef",
    "d3": "ffgfgf"
  }
}

var response = {};
recursive(obj, 0, response);
console.log("result:",response);


function recursive(passedObject, depth, response) {
    var keys = Object.keys(passedObject);
    response[depth] = response[depth] || [];
    response[depth].push(...keys);

    keys.forEach(function(key){
    if (passedObject[key] && typeof passedObject[key] === 'object') {
        recursive(passedObject[key], depth + 1, response)
    }
 })
}
```

***Output:***

```
result: 
{
 0 : ["a", "c"]
 1 : ["b1", "b2", "b3", "d1", "d2", "d3"]
}
```

Benchmarking results here:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could take an recursive approach by using an incremented level for each nested object. Then take the level for the result and for adding the keys of same level.

```js
function iter(object, level) {
    var keys = Object.keys(object);

    level = level || 0;
    result[level] = result[level] || [];
    Array.prototype.push.apply(result[level], keys);

    keys.forEach(function (key) {
        if (object[key] && typeof object[key] === 'object') {
            iter(object[key], level + 1);
        }
    });
}

var object = { a: { b1: "blah blah", b2: "ahsbefbasef", b3: "adsfad af" }, c: { d1: "asef", d2: "fefef", d3: "ffgfgf" } },
    result = [];

iter(object);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Alternatively you can use `Array.concat`.

Comment: In that case, you can also push inside loop. You are anyways looping on keys. Not sure about performance aspect though.

Comment: @Nina Scholz , is there a way to implement lazy approach here,as in i can pass to this method a node and it returns me all the immediate childrens and not more and so on and so forth and when i pass nothing it returns me all the parent nodes and nothing more

Comment: with parent, it does not work, because objects allows only to get the childrens. for getting only the childrens, you could use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).